# Different resource files for integration testing an asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, selenium, testing, specflow

My asp.net application uses a resource file to point to some REST api endpoints. The apps behavior changes depending on the amount of data it gets back from those services.

I'd like to perform integration testing on my app but I'd like to use different resource files that have custom api endpoints depending on the scenario I'd like to check against. For instance, I'd like to be able to test the integration of my app if the end points return nothing, one item, or many items.

In my ninject bindings I have

```
var appSettings = StreamDeserializer.DeserializeFileFromResource<AppStartSettings>(Resources.appsettings);
```

Is there a way I can configure specflow to rebuild my application with a different resource file depending on the integration test scenario?

Comment: For those curious, I was able to make some progress by using https://github.com/jakerella/jquery-mockjax to stub out my api end points

Answer (score 1):

No, SpecFlow runs only when you execute your tests and so can not influence your build.

Could you parameterize in your code, which resourcefile is used so that it is decided at runtime?

Then you could write a step that changes this parameter.